# BitBucket and Merge Conflicts

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a code source that has 3 branches to it:

```
master
Branch 1
Branch 2
```

I'm working on `Branch 2` while another programmer is working on `Branch 1`.

I have recently pushed my changes to my branch after having pulled any changes locally. Then I merged my branch with the master.

I'm now trying to merge his branch with the master but get a HUGE list of conflicts. Mostly things I added and synced to the master are conflicting with lines he added in the same files.

How do I decide which changes to keep of his so I can merge it all and bring it all up to date?

I tried creating a pull request inside bitbucket but couldn't get the hang of it. I tried inside that pull request editing X files and placing the Code I knew was good there, but the conflicts remained after edit.

Comment: So you are merging `Branch 1` into `master`, okay. In your working folder, make sure you don't have any uncommitted changes (i.e. `commit` or `stash` them) and then do `git checkout branch_1` followed by `gitk &` (assuming you have this installed and you are on Linux or Mac). Review his changes to make sure they are okay - conflicts either mean you've been working on the same files, or that something has gone wrong.

Comment: If the conflicts are legitimate then use a conflict resolver to fix them (unless you are happy to fix them manually in a text editor). NetBeans has a very good conflict resolver, in the Git submenu.

Answer (score 1):

- Your branch merged fine because there was no changes on master between you creating branch1 and you merging it back
- Since branch2 also originated from master - merge master into branch2 to keep it up-to-date
- Once branch2 is up-to-date, you can easily merge it  back to master